# How to rollback migration in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration, rollback

I've been able to create and run migrations in Codeigniter but I've not been able to rollback my migration. Can anyone help me how to rollback migration in codeigniter?

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

class Migration_Create_language extends CI_Migration {

```
public function up() {
    Capsule::schema()->create('languages', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 120);
        $table->string('country', 120);
        $table->string('country_code', 20);
        $table->enum('status', array('0','1'))->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/*
* Sample function for rolling back the above action
*/
public function down()
{
    Capsule::schema()->drop('languages');
}
```

}

Comment: https://github.com/AimalAzmi/codeigniter-migrations

Try this, I've written a library for this which can be used very easily through the CLI. It can be used to create migrations files and run migrations backwards or forwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your migration code?

There's a method called `down`in every migration. That's what it's executed when the migration happens downwards. Make sure that you have your sql statements in down, for example, to destroy a table. Then, load the migration version that you want.

Comment: I've query in my down function to rollback the migration. I just don't know how to execute them when I want to rollback my database.

Comment: You need to do:

`$this->migration->version(x);`

when x is the number of the migration you want to go. Codeigniter will understand if you're going down or not, because it saves your current migration version in your db.

Comment: ok. thanks, Matias. Is there a more simpler way to tell it to rollback just the last version?

Comment: You're welcome. 

I don't think so. It only can go to the lastest, and to an specific one. We'll have to wait for CI 4.

Comment: Just thought of a workaround: `$this->migration->current()-1` see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For Codeigniter 4 the correct answer is:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use Throwable;

class Migrate extends Controller {
    
    public function index(){
        $migrate = \Config\Services::migrations();

        try {
            //$migrate->latest();
            $migrate->regress(1);

            echo 'Migration complete';
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            print'<pre>';print_r($e);print'</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** the parameter passed to `regress()` is a BatchID which can be found in your migrations table. This is the version to roll back *too* - i.e. if your latest batch is 3 then you would lose Batch 2 and 3.